# Having trouble with AP computer science sample test problem

Tags: computer-science, array, problem-solving

I am currently taking AP Computer Science at my high school and while looking at some sample AP test problems I came across one that really confused me.

**Sample Problem**

[image: Sample Problem]

The answer to the problem is letter A but I don't seem to understand why that is the answer or how to even begin to try and solve a problem like this.

Comment: Mentally replace the name "mystery" in the function with a variety of common algorithms, and see if that sheds some light on what you should be looking at.

Comment: Or even better, plug some real values into the function and see what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is a recursive function, meaning it calls itself over and over again, each time reducing the size of the problem until it reaches a point where it no longer calls itself but returns a value. For them to reduce the size of the problem with each call what they do is pass a modified version of the parameters they received in the previous call.

This kind of questions require you to *"run the program in your head"*, meaning try to follow the execution path and being able to, at least to a certain extent, keep in mind the values of the variables in order to reproduce *"in your head"* what the computer would do with the code. Basically they're asking you to interpret and run the program in your brain. Obviously you can use pen and paper to help yourself. Also obvious is the fact that you have to have some basic programming knowledge.

Of course it's easier once we know that the answer is A.

You call the function by passing it the indexes of the first and last array elements, as well as the number you want to find how many elements of the array are less than, given that the array is sorted and ther are no duplicates.

First they find a rough middle position of the array.

If the middle element of the array is less than `num` then the function calls itself passing only the upper half of the array (in reality passing index values that would make the function process only that upper half of the array).

If the middle element of the array is greater than `num` then the function calls itself passing only the lower half of the array (in reality passing index values that would make the function process only that lower half of the array).

This two steps divide the problem in half every time.

There's a moment, after X number of calls, that one of the following happens:

1. We reduced the problem so much that now the indexes are exhausted (`low` and `high` overlap).
2. We find a number that is equals to `num`.

In the first case it would mean that there are no elements in the array that are less than `num` (because we began with a lower index zero) so zero is the number of elements less than `num`.

In the second case it would mean that the index of the element is how many elements in the array are lower than `num`.

In either of the last two cases the function no longer calls itself, and the value is returned up the stack call trace.

This only works because the elements are sorted and there are no duplicate values. If there were duplicate values and the program ends because of the second ending condition (`arr[mid]==num`) the returned value would be wrong because, out of the number of elements returned, at least one would not be less but equal than `n`.

Comment: Well, now I just feel really dumb. I was getting confused on what number I needed to pass through for "num" and I also wasn't sure how the answers were related to that (I think I was just reading the answers wrong). This is a great explanation that makes it really obvious to me so I thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Walk through the function using some actual data.

The preconditions say that your input array is going to be presorted, with no duplicates.  So let's make such an array (this is going to be mostly pseudocode):

```
arr = { 1,2,3,5,7,8,12,16,17,18 } // an array with 10 sorted, non-repeating values.
```

If we choose `6` for `num`, the call

```
mystery(0, arr.Length-1, num);
```

now becomes:

```
mystery(0, 9, 6);
```

I will leave it to you as an exercise to walk through the function using those values.

Don't forget that, in C-like languages, the array index starts at zero, so the indices of the above array elements count from zero to 9.